# React Native Context Menu Problem (Any solution excluding Astrocoders Selectable Text?)

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, webview

As you know many reading applications have a customized menu when users long press on text. There is a different menu instead of standard Android context menu (Copy-Paste-Select All)

For example: https://prnt.sc/w14pap (App XODO - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xodo.pdf.reader)
Video sample: https://streamable.com/pfm5kb

What I need:
When the user long presses on the text component, a customized menu must be shown
When the user extends selection, the customized menu mustn't be lost or should be shown again.
When users long press or extend selection, we must get start and end indexes of selection.
We are using the Text component because we can colorize/underline some words of text. (TextInput doesn't support partial styling)
Must be work on both iOS and Android devices (includes Xiaomi)

The only solution I found is react-native-selectable-text component.(https://github.com/Astrocoders/react-native-selectable-text)
But it stopped being developing and I can not add icons there and there is some problems in Android

Thanks very much for your response

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are using an EXPO-managed react-native project. If so, react-native-selectable-text is not able to work through that way. It is not integrated into the standard EXPO Go app which makes your app crash while trying to retrieve the view.